# Converting string format dd - mmm - yy to date

Tags: python, pandas

I am having some problems converting a string into a date format.
Specifically,

```
Date
0   31 Ott 2020
1   30 Ott 2020
2   29 Ott 2020
3   28 Ott 2020
4   25 Ott 2020
... ...
73  7 Apr 2020
74  2 Apr 2020
75  27 Mar 2020
76  24 Mar 2020
77  23 Mar 2020
```

I would like to convert into the format yyyy-mm-dd (e.g. 2020-10-31). I did as follows:

```
df['New_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d %B %Y')
```

but I got this error:

> ValueError: time data '31 Ott 2020' does not match format '%d %B %Y'
> (match)

The date seems to be Italian (Ott=Ottobre)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the locale before you convert the time. here's the [table of locales](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Table_of_locales)

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'it_IT.UTF-8') # sets to italy but can be any locale

df['New_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d %B %Y')
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error. The df['Date'] columns is dtype('O')

Comment: `%B` should instead be `%b` which is the abbreviated month name.